# clone google address autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box  which i have attached the google auto complete address feature.
While cloning , it is cloning the text box...but not able to get that autocomplete feature on the cloned text box.
The clone function is working on first textbox but after clone the auto complete address feature is not working
please help to go out of this..

below is my code..

**textbox code which i want to clone**

```
     To Address:
    <div class="product-item">
         <div class="float-left"><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" /></div>
         <div>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('to_address', array('required' => false,'label' => false, 'div' => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Enter to address', 'class' => 'form-control','id' => 'toaddress'));
        ?>
        </div> 
    </div>

 <input type="button" class = "readmore-btn" name="add_item" value="Add More" onClick="addMore();" />
<input type="button" class = "readmore-btn" name="del_item" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow();" />
```

**Below is the google auto complete address script.**

```
    <script>
  function initialize() {     
        var address1 = (document.getElementById('toaddress'));       
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address1);
        //autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
        //autocomplete.setTypes(['establishment']);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
            }

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
        }

        document.getElementById('tolat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('tolong').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
        });
  }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

**Below is my clone function**

```
<script>
function addMore() {
    $(".product-item:last").clone().insertAfter(".product-item:last");  
}
</script>
```

Comment: reinitialize your plugin on the new cloned element

Comment: this is a basic mistake that lot of people make not realising that its must be unique on a page

Comment: change the id to another UNIQUE id or use a class

Comment: @madalinivascu please write a real answer with a code example, don't use the comments.

Comment: @Soviut i can't create a complete answer right now, when i will have enough info i will provide it

Comment: i change my clone function into jquery...now plz suggest ..

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, an ID is considered globally unique; There should only ever be one element with a particular ID. If two elements have the same ID, bad things happen.

**GOOD**

```
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>
```

**BAD**

```
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element1"></div>
```

Any JavaScript that selects an element by ID such as `getElementById()` will only find the first instance and ignore any others. If multiple identical elements on the same page do the same thing, they should use classes. You can find these elements by class using `getElementByClassName()`.

When you clone your element, use `addClass()` to add a class to the clone. You can then call `initialize()`, but replace the `getElementById()` with `getElementByClassName()`, searching for that same class. This will apply your autocomplete to multiple elements.

**NOTE:** You should really decide if you're going to use raw javascript or JQuery, because you're mixing both and it's making your life a lot harder. You could be using JQuery to act directly inside the `initialize()`, however, that's beyond the scope of this answer.